# Link on two tables if not all values between fields match in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables

```
exchange_rates:
curr1    curr2    rate
USD      GBP      0.81
EUR      GBP      0.98

transactions
TIMESTAMP    user    curr    amt
2017-01-01   u1      EUR     89
2017-01-01   u2      GBP     3
2017-01-03   u2      USD     10
```

I want to link `exchange_rates` and `transactions` and multiply `amt` by the corresponding exchange rate in GBP in `exchange_rates`. e.g. in line 3 of `transactions` we would multiply 10 by 0.81 to get 8.1. **BUT** if the amount is in GBP in the `transactions` table I want to leave that unchanged.

I have tried to use CASE and link the two table like this

```
select
trans.TIMESTAMP, trans.user
case
  when trans.currency != "GBP" then trans.amt*er.rate
  else trans.amt
end as "Converted Amount"
from exchange_rates er, transactions trans
where trans.curr = er.curr1
```

But this doesn't work when `curr` in `transactions` is GBP (line 2) since there is not `curr1`=GBP in `exchange_rates`... can anyone advise what the logic would be here to solve this?

DESIRED RESULT:

```
TIMESTAMP    user    converted amt
2017-01-01   u1      87.22
2017-01-01   u2      3
2017-01-03   u2      8.1
```

Comment: Just use an `outer join` instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a record in `exchange_rates` that defines a 1 to 1 exchange rate for GBP:

```
curr1    curr2    rate
GBP      GBP      1
```

Aside from that you can also use a left outer join to include all the matching records in the source table, regardless if the joined table matched: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-left-join/

```
select
    trans.TIMESTAMP, trans.user,
    trans.amt * coalesce(er.rate, 1) as "Converted Amount"
from transactions trans
left join exchange_rates er on er.curr1 = trans.curr
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t.TIMESTAMP, t.user,
       t.amt * coalesce(er.rate, 1) as converted_amount
from transactions t left join
     exchange_rates er 
     on t.curr = er.curr1 and er.curr2 = 'GBP';
```

Why does this look a bit different from your query?

First, it uses a `left join`.  Second, it compares *both* currencies.  It also simplifies the logic for the lookup.